# Gatsby - cannot find module react

Tags: gatsby

Using `gatsby-cli@2.12.98`

I have started to learn Gatsby.js and I stucked on first step. After installing gatsby-cli I cannot start new project. I have empty folder and I am running this command:

```
gatsby new gatsby-tutorial
```

After this command I am getting error

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/yoga-layout-prebuilt/yoga-layout/build/Release/nbind.js:53
> throw ex;
> ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'react'

I was looking for some advices in web but people are getting this message after installing some plugins etc. but I am getting this while I want to create a new project.

I am getting this error even with this command:

```
gatsby
```

My node version: `12.8.3` and I have installed gatsby-cli with this command:

```
sudo npm i -g gatsby-cli
```

Comment: what's your gatsby version

Comment: This is a temporary issue, please follow along here: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/26919

Comment: @DenisTsoi gatsby-cli@2.12.98

Comment: moving to `gatsby-cli@2.12.99` or downgrading to `gatsby-cli@2.12.97` may resolve this

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that but still I am getting this error, I have installed 'react' globally and it works now, it's kind a weird that gatsby-cli needs react to be installed globally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that by installing "react" globally with:

`npm i -g react`

There is some issues with this version of gatsby-cli that you can read about here:

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10712